# Getting error in internet shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, internet

I create a file by `url` extension and type following text into in(its url is sample):

```
[Internet Shortcut]
URL=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV
```

In some case i gettin this error:`"The Target "" of this Internet Shortcut is not valid. Go to the internet shortcut property sheet and make sure the target is correct."` (for sample if in path or name of target file exist space character)

my default browser in `Firefox`. I want have a internet shortcut that open in all browser and on al os.
What can I fixed it problem?

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am self taught english language)

Comment: Try replacing the space with `%20`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I do your suggestion but I still getting previous error .

Comment: Please give an example of a URL that does not work. [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding) is all that should be required to make it work.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I wrote it in original my question. It is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to create the "Internet Short-cut" file by visiting the website using your browser and then dragging the symbol to the left of the URL from the browser onto the desktop.

You can then view the resulting .url file to see the correct formulation or rename or move the file to another directory/folder as needed.

Comment: You're right, this approach worked but I want know :What my way don't worked.

Comment: The file is cached, so when you edited your file to fix the typo, you were still getting the old cached-typo link. See my comment in othe answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typo in the section keyword, there is no space. It's just one word "InternetShortcut", not "Internet Shortcut".

You can view the syntax of other sections and keywords of this file type, by dragging a shortcut from your browser to your desktop, and then viewing that shortcut as a text file. Here's what google.url looks like:

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.google.com/
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com/
IDList=
IconFile=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
IconIndex=1
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
```

And here's what each field means: [guide to url file format](http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html)

Comment: I remove space between `Internet` and `Shortcut`,but still getting error.

Comment: When I tried this, its seemed as if the url shortcut was being cached - so editing/saving/click on shortcut, would not work either. Instead, I had to save the edited file to a new filename (or maybe clear cache would work.) Then it worked ok. You can verify this by changing the URL destination, and see that clicking on the .url file still will go to the old destination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.  Eventually figured out since I had switched domains and moved contents from an old profile to a new one, the permissions were applying for that user on the old domain and not the new one.  Was clued in to this by being able to open the .URL files in her Favorites as a local admin, but not her.

Had to open up properties of Favorites and do Security -> Advanced -> Replace permissions...

This was on an XP machine, so I figured a similar Vista KB recommendation didn't necessarily apply!